# Why is conda build appending py27_0 to my package name if I'm building under python 3.6.1?

Tags: python, conda

I'm trying to make a conda recipe for [ProjectQ](http://projectq.ch). Something weird is going on during the build process under both linux and osx. I can build and install the package by hand (i.e. using 'python setup.py install' from the cloned git repo directory). However, when I make a recipe that does exactly the same thing, it fails. On both linux and osx.

My build recipe is [here](https://github.com/rpmuller/conda-recipes/tree/master/projectq). What is particularly weird is that even though I specify python 3.6.* under the build requirements in the meta.yaml file, the conda-build procedure names the package "projectq-v0.3.0-py27_0", and when it installs the package, it tries to do so in one of the python 2.7 directories, which is what I assume makes it fail.

So clearly I'm doing something dumb, but I can't for the life of me figure out what. Can anyone see anything I've done wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay, I've found one dumb mistake, that fixed one curiousity but didn't make the whole thing work. I needed to specify "python 3.6.*" under both the build and the run requirements in the meta.yaml file. I had only done the former, and the package name is determined by the latter. Makes sense. So now the package is called the right thing "projectq-v0.3.0-py36_0", but it still fails when it tries to install stuff in one of the python2.7 library directories. Still fails on both macosx and linux (which in my experience means that I've done something dumb).

Comment: What is your root conda install's Python version? If it isn't 3.6, try specifying the python version on the command line - `conda build projectq --python=3.6`

Comment: @darthbith Thanks, I tried that, and I've also tried specifying "python 3.6.*" in the dependencies. I'm building the proper executable (I get the "py36_0" ending on the package name), but installation still fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. Thanks to everyone who took the time to look over my question. There was truly no way that anyone could have figured this out for me, since it was rather specific to the package I was installing. I'm going to try to summarize what I've learned in case someone else runs into anything different.

1. First, as I noted in one of the comments, if you're specifying a specific version requirement under the build, you had better specify the same version requirement under run. Initially I had "python 3.6.*" specified under build, but just "python" under run. This caused the package to be named something ending with "-py27_0", since the package name, understandably, depends upon what's required to **run** it, not to build it.
2. The really tricky thing was to understand that there were additional requirements specified in the setup.py script that were being installed automatically when I ran "python setup.py install" by hand, but were **not** being run when I tried to build under conda. Once I added these requirements to the meta.yaml recipe, everything builds and tests fine.

So, the lessons are to be consistent with your conda requirements between build and run, and make sure you have all of the requirements listed, including *bonus* requirements that may be specified in the setup.py file.

Thanks again to all who looked at this.

Comment: You can automatically handle the Python dependency by writing something like this in the build: https://github.com/Cantera/conda-recipes/blob/master/cantera/meta.yaml#L20 and see below for the runtime dependency. That way, when you write `conda build projectq --python=X.Y` its handled automagically :-) (disclaimer: I'm the author of that code, but I'm not affiliated with Continuum, so that might not be the "proper" way of doing it)

Comment: The values in double brackets are Jinja variables that are filled in by the build script based on variables that are set during the build process

Comment: @darthbith Thanks again for the tip. And thanks for working on Cantera (I was friends with Goodwin when he was working on it).

Comment: Ha! Small world! The documentation for conda build isn't the best, happy to share my experience :-)